# How to test CRUD operation API without database interaction?

Tags: java, mocking, junit4, crud

How to test CRUD operation API without database interaction i.e with mock connection in Junit?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to test/validate and what you need to mock.

Comment: API is an Interface. Interface doesn't have any implementation. Tests are testing implementations. Your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

You may use db mock
https://www.npmjs.com/package/db-mock
or use mockito https://github.com/mockito/mockito

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an ORM like Hibernate and do not issue any vendor specific SQL statements, you can also use an in-memory DB like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Postman App Extension For Google Chrome,
[Get Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?utm_source=gmail)
This Works Well for MongoDB and API declared in Express.js.
Dont worry this will work with your Junit as Well.